# CSS button image resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a button with an image on it, though image is stretching to fit inside the button. I want to stop it from doing so and center the image vertically and horizontally but can't find a way to do so since the image is added to the button using the src attribute.

```
    <div id="form">
        <input type="text"  value="Name">
        <input type="text"  value="Email">
        <textarea rows="7">Message</textarea>
        <input id="button" type="image" src="Images/send_icon.png">     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use background size property it may be solve your problem.

```
background:url('imagepath') center no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must stylise your button or input with CSS :

```
input#button{
  background-image : url(Images/send_icon.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And remove the type='image' of your html.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't change the HTML, you can try adding padding to the `<input>`:

```html
<style>
    #button {
        /* ugly green background color, but it serves to show the area of 
           the button */
        background-color: green;
        
        /* Setting the size of the button. Set only the width or the
           height, to prevent stretching the image */
        width: 300px;
            
        /* By adding padding, we can change the position of the image 
           inside the button */
        padding-top: 70px;
        padding-bottom: 80px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }
</style>
<input id="button" type="image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=71aa9dd4a5bb" />
```

But really, changing the HTML to get rid of the `type="image"` part is a better solution overall. See the other excellent answers.